# need help : google, yahoo, hotmail contacts api

Tags: facebook, api, contacts, addressbook

i want to import addressbook contacts from Gmail, Windows Live, and Yahoo just like Facebook.

In facebook, when i click on Windows live importer, a popup comes with a login page of Windows live.
how can i do that? can anyone suggest me a tutorial or reading material to learn about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Gmail, [Google Contacts Data API](http://code.google.com/intl/zh-CN/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide.html).

For Windows Live, [Windows Live: Contacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/ff759524.aspx).

For Yahoo!, [Yahoo! Contacts API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/).

Answer (score 0):

CloudSponge does everything in a single integration (including desktop address books like Outlook and Mac Address Book)

I work there, let me know if you have questions.