# How to extract the gmail and yahoo contacts to my iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, import-contacts

I started with the new project where i have to fetch the gmail and yahoo contacts to my iphone Application, I googled a lot but didn't find any solution apart from GData, any tutorials or solutions would be very helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: For google account contacts, have you tried this, https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/

Comment: Try to do some google...your question is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268819/need-help-google-yahoo-hotmail-contacts-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have made demo using GDATA for gmail contact, you can download it from [here](https://github.com/nileshkikani/GmailContactImporter)

Also for yahho i have tried my best but i didn't succeed so my advice to you that don't work for yahoo it's very hard to import yahoo contacts in application then also if you want to try and get success then please inform me.

Let me know your review on this demo. one more thing you are able to run this demo only on iphone device, if you want to run it on simulator then you need to do some setting in project setting.

Also don't forgot to add you gmail id and password here

```
#define gmailID ""
#define gmailpass ""
```

Wish you best of luck.

Comment: @nilesh your code on github crashes on running in Xcode 5.1

Comment: is it possible to get contact without passing gmailID, and gmailpass

Comment: @TusharJain Sorry that's not possible. You must need to enter your id and password to fetch contact.